# Name table in SQLite-net

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime, sqlite-net

I'm building a Windows 8 C#/XAML app that uses SQLite as a storage database, and I'm trying to create multiple tables using the SQLite-net syntax.

From what I've researched so far, a table is created based off of a class. First, I've created an "Account" class via:

```
public class Account
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set;}
}
```

And then create a table and enter in initial data later on in the code via:

```
    private static readonly string _dbPath =
        Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "data.sqlite");


        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(_dbPath))
        {
            db.CreateTable<Account>();

            db.RunInTransaction(() =>

               db.Insert(new Account()
                    {
                        Name = "MyCheckingAccount",
                        Type = "Checking",
                    })
                    );
        }
```

I want to create multiple account tables, but the `db.CreateTable<Account>()` syntax just creates a table and the data is inserted into the columns with `db.Insert().` I don't see where to enter the name of the table itself.

How do I create multiple tables, i.e. one named "BusinessAccounts" and another "PersonalAccounts" based off of the Account class?

Is there a way to do this with SQLite-net? Or do I need to write out the SQLite command explicitly somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sqlite-Net uses the class name to create the table, as well as to update the data. To do what you want, you'll need to create separate classes. One way to get around repeating common fields is to use inheritance:

```
public class Account
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set;}
}

public class BusinessAccounts : Account { }

public class PersonalAccounts : Account { }
```

To create tables:

```
db.CreateTable<BusinessAccounts>();
db.CreateTable<PersonalAccounts>();
```

To insert data:

```
db.Insert(new BusinessAccounts() {...});
db.Insert(new PersonalAccounts() {...});
```

Just a note that the above code is untested. You'll want to make sure that the tables are created correctly (e.g. with the proper primary key and autoincrement field).

Comment: Ok thanks. How would I handle user input? i.e. Every time the user creates an account, a table is created  with the name given by the user. Is this possible?

Comment: @smillerc - What you are trying to do is not a good fit for Sqlite-Net. As I said above, Sqlite-Net uses the class name for the table name and data updates. A possible alternative would be to create one Accounts table that has a field to indicate the type of account.

Comment: Are there other good alternatives that would still pass certification for the app store? I've only ever seen examples with SQLite-net...

Comment: @smillerc - I don't have any experience with alternatives to Sqlite-net, so I can't really recommend any. Google will probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 8):

This answer seems to be outdated, in SQLite-net you can now use an attribute on a class to ovverride the table name, for example:

```
[SQLite.Table("table_customers")]
public class Customer
    {
        [MaxLength(3)]
        public string code { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]            
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

So it will create/update that table.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add that with SQLite-net, you can change the attribute of the class by implementing an initialisation overload and setting the SQLite.TableAttribute like this:

```
[Table("Account")]
public class Account
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public Account(string name = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            TableAttribute attrname = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this)(0);
            attrname.Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

The name defaults to account, but if you initialize the class with a string, it sets the attribute thus you can then create a table with that name.

Comment: I want to use this but can't see how to initialise the table passing in a name.  Also, those braces should be square brackets on the zero.